# After trying to find last populated row, my macro won't stop running

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste the value of one cell to every cell in column 10 of a table.  However, I only want it to do so for populated rows.  After adding these lines of code, the macro runs endlessly.

```
Worksheets("Inspections").Activate     

With Worksheets("Inspections")
    rowq = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range(.Cells(3, 10), .Cells(rowq, 10)).Value = Range("L1").Value
End With
```

Comment: `rowq = .Range("A" & .cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row)`

Comment: How large is your table and what range does it cover -  ColA to Col?

Comment: the table is 10 columns and about 100 rows.  I tried using the suggestion from @Davesexcel but am having the same problem.

Comment: runs just once here. Something else is going on. ?Event code?

Comment: Would that code happen to be written in a `Worksheet_Change` event handler by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using this code.  Still not sure why the original didn't work.

```
   With Worksheets("Inspections")
         rowq = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                     After:=Range("A1"), _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                     MatchCase:=False).row
         Range(.Cells(3, 10), .Cells(rowq, 10)).Value = Range("L1").Value
    End With
```